# How to continue an "mdadm --grow" after a reboot?

Tags: raid, mdadm

One of my mates has rebooted a server during a reshape. The command I initiated several days ago was:

```
sudo mdadm --grow /dev/md227 --level=6 --raid-devices=7 --backup-file=/root/raid5backup
```

It's actually a raid +LVM.

I have read [here](http://www.spinics.net/lists/raid/msg40771.html) that it wasn't catastrophic if it was a clean shutdown. Here is the state of the RAID now:

```
/dev/md227:
        Version : 1.2
     Raid Level : raid0
  Total Devices : 7
    Persistence : Superblock is persistent

          State : inactive

      New Level : raid6
     New Layout : left-symmetric
  New Chunksize : 512K

           Name : DOCKER-BATCAVE:227
           UUID : 837da647:3c4431c9:607feb30:b887f4fd
         Events : 1901220

    Number   Major   Minor   RaidDevice

       -       8      176        -        /dev/sdl
       -       8       17        -        /dev/sdb1
       -       8       33        -        /dev/sdc1
       -       8       49        -        /dev/sdd1
       -       8       65        -        /dev/sde1
       -       8       81        -        /dev/sdf1
       -       8      113        -        /dev/sdh1
```

example of one drive :

```
/dev/sdf1:
          Magic : a92b4efc
        Version : 1.2
    Feature Map : 0x5
     Array UUID : 837da647:3c4431c9:607feb30:b887f4fd
           Name : DOCKER-BATCAVE:227
  Creation Time : Wed Dec  2 22:22:58 2015
     Raid Level : raid6
   Raid Devices : 7

 Avail Dev Size : 3906764800 (1862.89 GiB 2000.26 GB)
     Array Size : 9766912000 (9314.45 GiB 10001.32 GB)
    Data Offset : 252928 sectors
   Super Offset : 8 sectors
   Unused Space : before=252840 sectors, after=9216 sectors
          State : clean
    Device UUID : 0d3ed1a6:2a816cfc:0938be54:235cecec

Internal Bitmap : 8 sectors from superblock
  Reshape pos'n : 9127587840 (8704.75 GiB 9346.65 GB)
     New Layout : left-symmetric

    Update Time : Tue Sep 20 00:14:15 2016
  Bad Block Log : 512 entries available at offset 72 sectors
       Checksum : 8ec55576 - correct
         Events : 1901220

         Layout : left-symmetric-6
     Chunk Size : 512K

   Device Role : Active device 3
   Array State : AAAAAAA ('A' == active, '.' == missing, 'R' == replacing)
```

What should I do? I can't find a straight answer to that problem. Should I do a `--grow--continue` or should I do an assemble?

I really don't know what to do.

Comment: Do you have the file /root/raid5backup available?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It happens to be finally very simple because of my backup file. I hop it will help guys like me who didn't find enough documentation about how to restart a grow after a clean reboot:

```
mdadm --stop /dev/md...
mdadm --assemble --backup-file location_of_backup_file  /dev/md...
```

it should restore the work automatically
you can verify it with

```
mdadm --detail /dev/md....
```

and `cat /proc/mdstat`

Answer (score 4):

As additional to vigilian (since it's still top link on google "mdadm continue reshape").

If you don't have backup file, you still can continue to reshape, you need to stop array with

```
mdadm --stop /dev/mdX
```

and then force assemble it with

```
mdadm --assemble --scan --force /dev/mdX
```

This will continue reshape.

P.S. Also, if you are reading it while reshape already ongoing and you wanna reboot - before reboot do (where X is number of your md)

```
echo frozen > /sys/block/mdX/md/sync_action
```

P.S. Since i can't comment, I wrote this

Comment: If you get `mdadm: /dev/mdX not identified in config file.` you can just `mdadm --assemble /dev/mdX /dev/sdY /dev/sdZ ...`